# Update INotifyPropertyChanged-property from ViewModel in another thread WinRT

Tags: multithreading, mvvm, windows-8

I have a property that `RaisePropertyChanged(PropName, oldValue, true, true)` when I don't have any connection to the internet no more but it throws the exception that I'm on the wrong thread.
So I want to update the property form my ViewModel but how do I get the current thread in my ViewModel or what is you proposal for a solution?

My ViewModel-ctor

```
public MyViewModel()
{
   // START LISTENING TO NETWORKSTATUS
   NetworkInformation.NetworkStatusChanged += OnNetworkStatusChangedHandler;
}
```

NetworkChanged-callback method

```
   private async void OnNetworkStatusChangedHandler(object sender)
   {
       ConnectionProfile profile = NetworkInformation.GetInternetConnectionProfile();

       if (profile == null)
       {
          IsRefreshEnabled = false;
       }
       else
       {
          IsRefreshEnabled = true;
       }

   }
```

My Property

```
public const string IsRefreshEnabledPropertyName = "IsRefreshEnabled";
        private bool _isRefreshEnabled = true;
        public bool IsRefreshEnabled
        {
            get { return _isRefreshEnabled; }

            set
            {
                if (_isRefreshEnabled == value) { return; }

                var oldValue = _isRefreshEnabled;
                _isRefreshEnabled = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(IsRefreshEnabledPropertyName, oldValue, value, true);
            }
        }
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to replace the RaisePropertyChanged call to:

```
await Dispatcher.RunAsync(DispatcherPriority.Normal, (){RaisePropertyChanged(IsRefreshEnabledPropertyName, oldValue, value, true)});
```

That will cause the call to RaisePropertyChanged to run on the UI thread.

I'm assuming that your class derives from a Xaml control (to access the Dispatcher property on the control).

Comment: I think its bad to put `Dispatcher.RunAsync` in the setter of a property as it will run also when the property is changed in the UI thread. Its better to change the property in `RunAsync`. This way the method is only called when it's needed...

Comment: How can you implement this to an observablecollection?